# How to delete 0 in between part number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to delete 0 in between alpha numeric "Part Number".

Part Number Expected output
0-1379095-2 1379095-2
0-0042899-3 42899-3
0-0185309-1 185309-1

[image]

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(I8,"-0","-")
```

**EDIT:**

Your edit asks a totally different question. Assuming the pattern you show is consistent, you could use this horrendous formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(I8,FIND("-",I8,FIND("-",I8)+1)-1),"-","")),RIGHT(I8,LEN(I8)-FIND("-",I8,FIND("-",I8)+1)+1))
```

Or you could use a small UDF:

```
Function GaneshFormat(ByVal sInput As String, ByVal sSeparator As String) As String
    Dim s() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    s = Split(sInput, sSeparator)
    For i = 1 To UBound(s)
        s(i - 1) = CLng(s(i))
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve s(UBound(s) - 1)
    GaneshFormat = Join(s, sSeparator)
End Function
```

Which you can use like this:

```
=GaneshFormat(I8,"-")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked like Gem. However I found few other scenario's based on that I have edited the question. It would be of great help if you could help me with the formula to get the desired output. Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(LEFT($A2,5)="0-000",REPLACE($A2,1,5,""),IF(LEFT($A2,4)="0-00",REPLACE($A2,1,4,""),IF(LEFT($A2,3)="0-0",REPLACE($A2,1,3,""),IF(LEFT($A2,2)="0-",REPLACE($A2,1,2,""),IF(LEFT($A2,1)="0",REPLACE($A2,1,1,""),IFERROR(IF(FIND("-0",$A2,1)=2,REPLACE($A2,FIND("0",$A2,1),1,""),$A2),A2))))))
```